# Differences between “tout à trac”, “de but en blanc”, “tout de go“, “à brûle-pourpoint”

Tags: sens, expressions, usage

> Mais papa, tu ne peux pas décider **tout à trac** de divorcer de maman après 54 ans de mariage !
>
> Mais papa, tu ne peux pas décider **de but en blanc** de divorcer de maman après 54 ans de mariage !
>
> Mais papa, tu ne peux pas décider  **tout de go** de divorcer de maman après 54 ans de mariage !
>
> Mais papa, tu ne peux pas décider **à brûle-pourpoint** de divorcer de maman après 54 ans de mariage !

I think they all mean that you decide unexpectedly and suddenly. How do those synonyms actually differ in nuances and usages?

Comment: To be honest I have almost never seen or heard these idioms except *de but en blanc* so I cannot answer your question but I'd like to add that the most widely used would be *sur un coup de tête*.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Oui, Dasshoes l'a déjà indiqué dans sa question.

Comment: Stating *de maman* is redundant. Whom *papa* is divorcing is quite implicit.

Comment: Personnellement c'est la première fois que je vois "tout à trac"

Answer (score 1):

*Tout à trac* and *à brûle-pourpoint* I would use with verbs implying some kind of verbal interaction such as *dire* or *demander*.  I'm not sure *décider* and *tout de go* go well together.  *Décider de but en blanc* is ok.  But in your example, since we have 54 years of marriage and a sudden decision to divorce in the balance, I'd say :

- Mais papa, tu ne peux pas décider du jour au lendemain de divorcer de maman après 54 ans de mariage !

To sum up, it's more a question of finding the right verb to go with each of the four expressions than a question of nuances of meaning between them.